# Sort Map<String, List<Object[]>>

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary

Is there an efficient way of sorting a Java Map that has List as value?
I have string as a key, and I'm trying to sort values that I have in my Object List.

```
Map<String, List<Object[]>> liste = new TreeMap<String, List<Object[]>>();
```

Comment: For each of the entries of the map you would like to sort the values (lists)?

Comment: Provide a sample data which you need to sort and on what basis?

Comment: Exactly, I need to sort them by id value, which is Integer.
So, for each key, I have Integer and String value in my object list, and I need to sort them by id, from lowest number to highest

Comment: If you are just trying to sort the lists and not the map itself, just iterate through the map entry set and call sort method on each value.

Comment: I think that best way is sort before adding them to map, or create your own structure and comparator for your own implementation of Map with List.

Comment: instead of using Object[], can't you use comma separated string("id,StringValue")? that way you can call sort method on list of string.

Answer (score 1):

This will sort the lists by the `Integer` object in the first array entry:

```
    for (List<Object[]> list : liste.values()) {
        list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(arr -> ((Integer) arr[0]).intValue()));
    }
```

It seems to me that you haven’t done you design work properly, though? For most applications you should not need to use `Object[]`. Better to design your own class, with an `int` (or `Integer`) `id` and other fields. Also your data and requirements are not completely clear to me, so I hope I’m on the same track as you.

Comment: yes, you helped. tnx a lot